# ISO brief primer on special matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request

I am looking for a brief primer on the following types of matrices: stochastic, doubly stochastic, symplectic, Vandermonde, Hadamard, permutation, tridiagonal and circulant.

Nothing too deep, just a bit to study for my written qualifiers, where problems involving these sometimes come up. Can anyone recommend a good resource to learn about the basic properties?  I'm pretty well-versed at linear algebra,  and have read Strang, Roman, Lax, etc. (Lax does mention the first four types above, and I will be consulting that source, hopefully among others. Lax isn't always good for an introduction to a topic.)

Bonus if it's an online resource.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider the [Matrix Reference Manual](http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/matrix/intro.html) by [Mike Brookes](http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/dmb.html). In particular, the [Special Matrices](http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/matrix/special.html) page contains discussion of all of these matrix types, and more.

I would say that your browser's search feature will be helpful here. Don't just look for the *main definition* of a given matrix type, search the whole page for places where the term appears. For instance, the definition of "doubly stochastic" is quite short, but a number of the other special matrix types are themselves doubly stochastic, so that will give you more insight into when that property arises in practice.

Comment: Re the bounty, I looked over that resource, and while I appreciate your answer, it wasn't quite what I was looking for. The treatment of the special matrices was sort of cursory (didn't have many tools to aid in calculation) and didn't have any exercises. So I'm going to keep looking for answers, rather than award you the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can see more of the applications and properties of these types of matrices in chapter 2 of http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~ramani/pubs/zhihui_thesis.pdf